# pouchdb, the view creation seems making normal data unavailable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pouchdb

I don't understand the possibity to create a view like Couchdb.
When i create a db in couchdb without views, i can replicate in pouchdb.
I can use the datas to print in table with D3.js, but when i create a view
in couchdb or pouchdb, the datas seems to exist but the requests with the same code seems to get trouble.

```
(function(p_url, p_debug) {
'use strict';
var debug = p_debug;
var url = p_url;
var ENTER_KEY = 13;
var synStart = document.getElementById('synchronize');
var printArray = document.getElementById('printArray');
var printGraph = document.getElementById('printGraph');
var destroydb = document.getElementById('delete');
var dbOptions = {
   auto_compaction : false,
   cache : false
};
var db = new PouchDB('dblocal',dbOptions);
var remoteCouch = url;

/* getRemoteDB sans filter */
function getRemoteDB(remote) {
    db.replicate.from(remoteCouch).on('complete', function() {
        console.log('complete');
    }.on('error', function() {
        console.log('error replicate');
    }));
}

/* getRemoteDB by filter */
function getlocalDB(filter) {

}

function reset() {
    db.destroy().then(function(response) {
        console.log('destroy success');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
// The table generation function
function tabulate(id, data, columns) {
    var table = d3.select(id).append("table")
            .attr("style", "margin-left: 20px; border: solid 1px black;"),
            thead = table.append("thead"),
            tbody = table.append("tbody");
    // append the header row
    thead.append("tr")
            .selectAll("th")
            .data(columns)
            .enter()
            .append("th")
            .text(function(column) {
                return column;
            });
    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
            .data(data.etablissement)
            .enter()
            .append("tr");
    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function(column) {
                    return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                });
            })
            .enter()
            .append("td")
            .attr("style", "font-family: Courier; color : white;") // sets the font style
            .html(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });
    return table;
}


function showDatas() {
    var tab = document.getElementById('db_array');
    tab.innerHTML = '';
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}).then(function(doc) {
        var jsonvalues = {etablissement: []};
        doc.rows.forEach(function(row) {
            jsonvalues.etablissement.push({'numerouai': row.doc.etablissement.numerouai, 'reponses': row.doc.reponses[0].idreponse});
        });
        var dataset = jsonvalues;
        tabulate('#db_array', dataset, ['numerouai', 'reponses']);
        d3.select("db_graph").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <-B
                .data(dataset.etablissement)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "h-bar")
                .append("span");
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

function createViews() {
    var ddoc = {
        _id: '_design/questions',
        views: {
            id_question: {
                map: function(doc) {
                    emit(doc.etablissement.numerouai,doc.academie.codeaca);
                }.toString()
            }
        }
    };
    db.put(ddoc).then(function() {
        console.log('vue poussée');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

function getQuestions(i) {
    console.log('getQuestions');
    db.query('questions/id_question').then(function(res) {
        console.log('res');
        console.log(res.key);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

}
/* main function */
function sync() {
    console.log('synchronisation ...');
    synStart.addEventListener("click", getRemoteDB.bind(this, url));
    printArray.addEventListener("click", showDatas.bind(this));
    destroydb.addEventListener("click", reset.bind(this));
    printGraph.addEventListener("click", getQuestions.bind(this));
    createViews();
}
sync();
})('http://192.168.2.128:5984/eticdegre1', true);
```

making them unavailable data, but there is no error in console javascript.
Is it possible to have data and views in the same times like couchdb.
I'm newbie in PouchDB
thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please be more specific on what exactly is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite following your question, but I see a couple potential problems:

1) You are not re-creating the database after calling `db.destroy()`. When you `destroy()`, you need to call `new PouchDB()` again to use it again.

2) When you do `allDocs()`, you are using `{include_docs: true}`, but you are not doing the same thing when you `query()`. If you expect to get the docs back, you should do `query('questions/id_question', {include_docs: true})`.

Also in general, these kinds of questions may be better for the #pouchdb IRC channel or for the mailing list than StackOverflow. (See the "Discuss" links at the bottom of http://pouchdb.com/) Usually there is somebody there who can provide step-by-step guidance! :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. You found my script problems, now it works perfectly. the most important was  query('questions/id_question', {include_docs: true})

thanks